VsCode The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) was not found
I created a new net5 project using this command dotnet new webapi -n UserService --framework net5.0 I can run the app with dotnet run. But I cant debug it in VsCode. I get the error below. In my .cspoj file target framework is already set to net5.0. How can I debug my donet5.0 project in VsCode?
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.17

my .cspoj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


I solved the problem. The culprit was the new version of C# extension in VsCode. Looks like new versions doesn't support dotnet5. Installing the older version of the C# extension 1.24.1 solved the problem.

Thank you. The two related extensions - C# Dev Kit and .NET Install Tool should not be added. Reason: When C# extension 1.24.1 was out, C# Dev Kit even did not exist. For .NET Install Tool, it matters only if you have more than one version of .NET SDK and runtime in your system.
